# Including parameters seperated by space in Oclif CLI

Tags: typescript, command, command-line-interface, oclif

I am trying to build a CLI that consumes a Rest API using oclif.

My code is the following:

```
import Command from '@oclif/command'
import axios from 'axios'

export class AggregatedCommand extends Command {
  static args = [
    {name: 'Area', required: true},
    {name: 'AreaName', required : true},
    {name: 'timeres', required: true},
    {name: 'Resolution', required: true},
    {name: 'ProdType',required: true},
    {name: 'ProductionType',required:true},
    {name: 'dateformat', required: true},
    {name: 'dateinput', required: true},
    {name: 'beforeformat', required: false},
    {name: 'format' , required: false}
  ]
  async run() {

    const axios = require('axios');
    const {args} = this.parse(AggregatedCommand); 
    //console.log(`${args.format}`);
    if (`${args.dateformat}`=='--date'){
     var splitted = `${args.dateinput}`.split("-", 3); 
    // console.log('http://localhost:8765/energy/api/AggregatedGenerationPerType/' +`${args.AreaName}` +'/' + `${args.ProductionType}` +'/' + `${args.Resolution}` +'/date/' + splitted[0] +'-' + splitted[1] + '-' + splitted[2]);
     if (`${args.format}`== "undefined" || `${args.format}`=="json"){
     const data= await axios.get('http://localhost:8765/energy/api/AggregatedGenerationPerType/' +`${args.AreaName}` +'/' + `${args.ProductionType}` +'/' + `${args.Resolution}` +'/date/' + splitted[0] +'-' + splitted[1] + '-' + splitted[2]);
         console.log(data.data);
     }
     else if (`${args.format}`=="csv") {
         const data= await axios.get('http://localhost:8765/energy/api/AggregatedGenerationPerType/' +`${args.AreaName}` +'/' + `${args.ProductionType}` +'/' + `${args.Resolution}` +'/date/' + splitted[0] +'-' + splitted[1] + '-' + splitted[2]+ "/format=" + `${args.format}`);
         console.log(data.data);
     }
     else console.log("Error 400: Bad Request");

    }

    else if (`${args.dateformat}`=='--month'){
         var splitted = `${args.dateinput}`.split("-", 2); 
             if (`${args.format}`== "undefined" || `${args.format}`=="json"){
     const data= await axios.get('http://localhost:8765/energy/api/AggregatedGenerationPerType/' +`${args.AreaName}` +'/' + `${args.ProductionType}` +'/' +  `${args.Resolution}` +'/month/' + splitted[0] +'-' + splitted[1]);
                 console.log(data.data);
            }

         else if (`${args.format}`=="csv") {
         const data= await axios.get('http://localhost:8765/energy/api/AggregatedGenerationPerType/' +`${args.AreaName}` +'/' + `${args.ProductionType}` +'/' + `${args.Resolution}` +'/month/' + splitted[0] +'-' + splitted[1] + "/format=" + `${args.format}`);
         console.log(data.data);
        }

        else console.log("Error 400: Bad Request");
    }
```

I am trying to input a command like the following:

```
energy AggregatedGenerationPerType --area United Kingdom  --timeres PT15M --productionType AllTypes --year 2018
```

But oclif and typescript do not recognize the United Kingdom as one parameter but as two "United" and "Kingdom". How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already using flags in your example call you should switch to them instead of args. (see https://oclif.io/docs/flags).

> Arguments are positional arguments passed to the command
>
> Flag options are non-positional arguments passed to the command

Example:

```js
export class AggregatedCommand extends Command {
  static flags = {
    area: flags.string(),
    timeres: flags.string(),
    ...
  } 

  async run() {
    const {flags} = this.parse(AggregatedCommand)
    if (flags.area) console.log('--area is set')
    if (flags.timeres) console.log('--timeres is set')
  }
}
```

Then you can pass

```
energy AggregatedGenerationPerType --area "United Kingdom"  --timeres PT15M --productionType AllTypes --year 2018
```

Comment: yes but in this case this.parse(AggregatedCommand).flags.area's value would be just "United" because the value contains a space and oclif stops parsing the flag value when the first space is met, i'm facing the same issue

Comment: Should not be the problem as it parses the complete string. If you pass `--area United Kingdom` then only United will be parsed.